# Link multiple libraries or objects with the same name

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am working on a Fortran code which uses code written by other companies. We are given an un-compiled .f file that does some basic set-up, then calls a subroutine which is in a compiled .lib file. Unfortunately, some of these objects utilize the same names for subroutines and common variables. This isn't a case of compiled code conflicting with my code. This is a case of compiled code conflicting with other compiled code. I am unable to modify either library in any way.

For example, I have two separate fortran files alpha.f and beta.f which both call a subroutine SPAM(inputa, inputb). SPAM is defined inside a compiled .lib file. They are obviously meant to be compiled and run in separate scripts. I do not have access to the code for either SPAM.

Is there anyway to firewall the separate objects but still compile the code? Our current method (which is terrible) is to compile a separate version of our code for each different customer code. This means that any changes to our code must be propagated through many different versions. The customer codes contain proprietary information, so getting the raw code is impossible for us.

I am using Visual Fortran Compiler 17.0.5.267

These two files were delivered together:

SpamLibraryAlpha.lib (This is compiled, I do not have access to the source code)

```
subroutine SPAM(i,j)
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    integer,intent(out) :: j

    j = i + 1
    return
end subroutine SPAM
```

alpha.f90

```
module alphaMod
private
public alpha

contains
subroutine alpha(a,b)
    integer,intent(in) :: a
    integer,intent(out) :: b
    
    call SPAM(a,b)
    
    return
end subroutine alpha
end module alphamod
```

And these two files were delivered together:

SpamLibraryBeta.lib (This is compiled, I do not have access to the source code)

```
subroutine SPAM(i,j)
    integer,intent(in) :: i
    integer,intent(out) :: j

    j = i + 9999999
    return
end subroutine SPAM
```

beta.f90

```
module betaMod
private
public beta

contains
subroutine beta(a,b)
    integer,intent(in) :: a
    integer,intent(out) :: b

    call SPAM(a,b)

    return
end subroutine beta
end module betaMod
```

Here is what I'm trying to write

MyCode.f90

```
program MyCode
    use alphaMod
    use betaMod
    implicit none
    integer :: x,y,z

    y = 1

    do x = 1,2
        select case(OPTIND)
        case (1)     
            call alpha(y,z)
        case (2)     
            call beta(y,z)
        end select
    end do

end program
```

The compiler error I get is "error LNK2005: _SPAM already defined in alphaMod.obj"

Comment: I don't understand your updated problem detail. If `alpha.f` and `beta.f` have things which call the _same_ subroutine `spam` then why is this troublesome? That is part of the point of library objects

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose situation described some way. We need some actual example. Best some actual code and actual error messages. Is your company's code proprietary and too big? We would not like to see it all anyway. Just make a small code example that shows the same basic problem and causes the same error message. See [mcve].

Comment: Currently, I do not even understand if there are two different compiled libraries with two different `SPAM` subroutines or what exactly happens and what is the error you get. Please do not add any more wordy description. Show some actual code or, at least, the commands you are executing. If there is an error message if you do something you say you cannot do, please also show the error message.

Comment: I added some generalized sample code that shows what I'm trying to do.